# How can I convert a data frame in R to to a csv file without getting the following error? unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, data-science

I want to convert a data frame that I built in R (Web scraping) to csv format and export to excel/ download it onto my desktop. I have it as dataframe "allNYTSearch". I have run the is.data.frame function to confirm the object is indeed a data frame, however and it comes back as "[1] TRUE", however, I still get the following error.

I tried a few different google search answers however none have been successful as of yet.

```
Error in utils::write.table(allNYTSearch, "\\Users\\khalidali\\desktop\\allNYTSearch.csv",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

Comment: Hello Khalid, surely you data.frame contains list columns (created by dplyr or tibble). If the datatypes are compatible, you can unnest the lists with `allNYTSearch<- tidyr::unnest(allNYTSearch)`

Comment: What does `str(allNYTSearch)` return?